# Virtualbox is giving error at startup

Tags: virtualbox, 16.10

I've installed Virtualbox 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.10. when starting up virtualbox, it gives the following error:

> `supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain:`
>   `dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",)  failed:`
>   `libQt5X11Extras.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or`
>   `directory`

I cannot install the `libQt5X11Extras` library! Could anyone help here?

Regards, Is

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I used the deb file for ubuntu Yakkety using the command: sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.12-112440~Ubuntu~yakkety_amd64.deb. Thanks.

Comment: Actually i couldn't manage to install it directly from packages repositories!

Comment: Did you try the official Virtualbox ppa?  If not I suggest purging and trying that. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Many thanks. Issue resolved using. I made a mistake in resources.list, where I did not replace xenial to yakkty. Then did apt-get update and apt-get install debfile.deb. I aslo did dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-5.1. Then my problem was resolved. Thanks Much for your support.

Comment: I will post my suggestion as an answer, if it helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the official [Virtualbox ppa](http://virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)? If not I suggest purging and trying that.